# Where to catch exception using log4net in a MVC 3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, logging, exception, log4net

I  placed the following code in the global file to catch exception in my mvc application:

```
 void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
            log.Error("Exception", ex);
        }
```

and the following to trace what controllers are called:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                var loggingWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                filterContext.HttpContext.Items.Add(StopwatchKey, loggingWatch);

                var message = new StringBuilder();
                message.Append(string.Format("Executing controller: {0}, action: {1}",
                    filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
                    filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName));

                log.Debug(message);
            }
        }
```

Is there more I can do to catch errors involving db, security (like cannot connect to ldap), data issues/casting, etc..?

Comment: Just wondering how do I handle placing logging in DAL and helper classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code snippet could be added to a global action filter (registered in `global.asax`). The first snippet could be added to a seperate `IHttpModule` implementation to remove it from global.asax.

Other than that you've added code to the two places where all exceptions will be caught. The first one will be invoked for all non-MVC related exceptions while the later one is for MVC exceptions only (routing excluded)

Comment: Just wondering how do I handle placing logging in DAL and helper classes?

Comment: You don't (unless you handle them: http://blog.gauffin.org/2010/11/do-not-catch-that-exception). Those errors will be caught by the error filter.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense for exceptions.. . Would it be good practice to put tracing for each method Ex: log.Info('Executing GetAgency(id)') ?

Comment: Only if your methods are not robust. imho it's much better to always validate method arguments for reasonable data instead (and throw one of the argument exceptions if something doesn't validate). In that way you'll probably get the exception higher up in the callstack. And that makes debugging a LOT easier.